# TCPDF change font inside html

Tags: php, html, fonts, tcpdf

I converted the `.ttf` font i need (3 files), and included them inside the tcpdf fonts folder.

It works just fine when i use the classic `$pdf->SetFont();` call, but the problem is i dont know how to change font inside the html which is later called using `$pdf->writeHTML();`

Let us call it the font **X**.

For example:

```
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu Sans','',10);

$html = '
<table>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-family:X;"></span></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

What i want, is to use the dejavu sans font through all the document, except for the `<span>` inside the first `<td>` tag, where i need the font **X**. I tried using the `font-family` property but it does not work so far.

Comment: You won't be able to do that with only one writeHTML. You can use DomPDF if you want a real HTML to PDF transform.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Write this as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with only one writeHTML. You can use DomPDF if you want a real HTML to PDF transform.

Notice than you can do it using several writeHTML() functions, but it will be hard to place correctly your words.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2019, the accepted answer is not correct anymore. In short — it works nowadays!

I've tested the following example in **TCPDF 6.2.9**:

```
$pdf->AddFont('PTSans', '', 'ptsans.php');
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuSans', '', 'dejavusans.php')

/* Setting the font family: */
$pdf->setFont('PTSans', '', 9);

/* outputting with writeHTMLCell, which internally calls MultiCell(), 
 * which in turn uses writeHTML() for HTML 
 */
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 10, '', '', '<span style="font-family:DejaVuSans;">А</span>A (<span style="font-family:DejaVuSans;">Ö</span>Ö)')
```

I see the following (screenshot)

[image]

Note that I've tried writing the font family name as DejaVuSans, dejavusans, Deja Vu Sans, 'Deja Vu Sans' (with quotes) — all of these work, provided the font has the needed characters. I suppose that TCPDF lowercases the font family and strips whitespace from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'px', $defaultSize, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator('abcd.com');
$pdf->SetAuthor('Viraj');
$pdf->SetTitle('HTML Pages');
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage(null;
$pdf->setPageMark();
$pdf->SetFontSize(12);

//Load font front file path url
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/Users/Work/storage/app/public/Arial regular.ttf', '', '', 32);
echo $fontname;//"arial" use this font in html code
$pdf->AddFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);

//Load font front file path url
$fontname_ = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/Users/Work/storage/app/public/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf', '', '', 32);
echo $fontname;//"bebasneue" use this font in html code
$pdf->AddFont($fontname_, '', 14, '', false);

//HTML code start
$html = '<table border="0" cellpadding="10" style="width: 100%;"  >';
$html .= '<tr nobr="true" >';
$html .= '<td>';

//use loaded font here
$html .= '<font face="arial"  >The formatting rules are not configurable but are already optimized for the best possible output.</font>';
//use loaded font here
$html .= '<font face="bebasneue"  >The formatting rules are not configurable but are already optimized for the best possible output.</font>';

$html .= '</td>';
$html .=   "</tr>";
$html .=   "</table>";

//write html into pdf
$pdf->writeHTML($html);

//save file in output path
$filePath = storage_path('app/public/samplePDF.pdf");  
echo "PDF File - ".$filePath;
$pdf->Output($filePath, 'F');
```

Basically we need to use tag `<font face="bebasneue"  ></font>` to apply the loaded font into HTML code.

Comment: In case it catches anyone else out, it doesn't work if you use single quotes. So <font face="...">...</font> is fine, but <font face='...'>...</font> is not.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<font face="Arial" >Test تست </font>
```

change the font inside Html